# Doctrine - query returns nested arrays instead of one

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm doing this query

```
public function getRecommendedVendors($user)
{
    $q = $this->em->createQuery(
        "
          select cat.id
          from Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\Category cat
          inner join cat.users u
          where u = :user
        "
    );

    $q->setParameters(["user" => $user]);

    var_dump($q->execute());
    die;
    return $q->execute();
}
```

Doing `var_dump()` returns:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '10' (length=2)
```

Where I want it to return because I use the result inside `IN` statement:

```
array (size=2)
  0 =>
    'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    'id' => string '10' (length=2)
```

Comment: Try dumping like this. `$tmp = $q->execute(); var_dump($tmp[0]);` instead of var dumping the whole thing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What you experience is the default query behaviour: The first array “level” are the rows, the second “level” are the columns. Of course, you only have one column, therefore it looks a bit strange.

Instead of `execute()` you should use `getScalarResult()`. To learn more about this, read http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats